# "and time starts to move backwards at that point"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between opening and closing shifts?
Opening and mid shifts commonly start with a lot of downtime filled in with side-work **and time starts to move backwards at that point**. With that said, closing shifts tend to be longer, and more hours mean more money.

Source: Closing Shift- How I Learned to Love Working the Closing shift

I don't understand the phrase "and time starts to move backwards at that point" - Suppose you arrive at your office/factory at 8:00AM for the opening shift, how can "time move backwords" from the point 8:00AM? It sounds confusing to me. What does it mean?

Comment: For example: https://youtu.be/2Pbywpi64Tg?t=64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Time starts to move backwards" is an idiom meaning "time seems to go very very slowly" (because the person is bored of the "downtime filled with side-work"). It is casual usage and not meant to be taken literally.